# How to return the result of a previous pipeline stage into a new field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mern

I have this function that returns an array of Institution info:

```
const getInstitutionsInfo = async () => {
  const sum_current_students = {
    $addFields: { number_of_current_students: { $size: "$current_students" } },
  };
  const sort_by_largest_number_of_current_students = {
    $sort: {
      number_of_current_students: -1,
    },
  };
  
  const pipeline = [
    sum_current_students,
    sort_by_largest_number_of_current_students,
  ];
  const response = await Institution.aggregate(pipeline);
  return response;
};
```

The result is an array:

```
[Institution_1_data, Institution_2_data ... ]
```

where each `Institution_X_data` is an object.

I would like to add another stage to the pipeline in the end that would make the final result like this:

```
{
  result: [Institution_1_data, Institution_2_data ... ]
}
```

I tried different combinations of [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) but I couldn't achieve that result.

Comment: if you get `[Institution_1_data, Institution_2_data ... ]` why you dont use javascript to create an object with the results,  like `{result : [Institution_1_data, Institution_2_data ... ]}` , i mean why to construct this document inside the database?

Comment: @Takis_ 1. I am trying to improve my mastery over Aggregation. 2. There will be more opertations in the pipeline that require this step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$group` stage

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "result":{
      "$push" : "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uh3z20htbtp) | [System Variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables)

---

```
const getInstitutionsInfo = async () => {
  const sum_current_students = {
    $addFields: { number_of_current_students: { $size: "$current_students" } },
  };
  const sort_by_largest_number_of_current_students = {
    $sort: {
      number_of_current_students: -1,
    },
  };
  const group_students = {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      result: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
    }
  };
  
  const pipeline = [
    sum_current_students,
    sort_by_largest_number_of_current_students,
    group_students
  ];
  return await Institution.aggregate(pipeline);
};
```